# Try Catch block showing wrong error message

Tags: try-catch

Facing an issue in Dev C++ wherein the catch block is not showing the desired error message

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void mightGoWrong()
{
     bool error1;
     bool error2;
     if(error1)
     {
     throw "Issue encountered!!";
     }     
}
int main(void)
{
    try
    {
    mightGoWrong();
    }
    catch(int e)
    {
     cout << "Error Code is:  "<<e<<endl;
     }
     cout<<"Still running"<<endl;

}
```

The message is get is : Still Running.Need to know what i am doing wrong

Comment: What happens if you declare `bool error1 = true;`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your boolean variable before your code starts working.

It is considered best practice to always give your variables some default value. Your error1 value has no value assigned to it, therefore throw error never gets to complete its job.

Also you are throwing a string, so you need to catch a string not an int.

```
void mightGoWrong()
{
     bool error1=true;
     bool error2=true;
     if(error1)
     {
        throw "Issue encountered!!";
     }     
 }
 int main(void)
 {
   try
   {
     mightGoWrong();
   }
    catch(string e)
   {
     cout << "Error Code is:  "<<e<<endl;
   }
    cout<<"Still running"<<endl;

 }
```